# How to use requirement set 1.7 in OnSend?

Tags: javascript, outlook-web-addins

Office 365 OWA just ignores my add-in if the manifest contains the following:

```
...
<Requirements>
  <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.7">
    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
  </bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
<Hosts>
   <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
   <DesktopFormFactor>
   <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
       <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
       <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
          <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateSubject" />
       </ExtensionPoint>
   </DesktopFormFactor>
  </Host>
</Hosts>
...
```

However it works if I change "1.7" to "1.6".
Could you please help? Can I use the requirement set 1.7 in OnSend add-in?

Thanks, 
Victor Ivanidze

Comment: As listed by Brian below, the add-in won't work on some clients if setting 
 requirement set to 1.7 now.

Answer (score 1):

OOTW supports up to 1.6 according to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#clients

Comment: Also, use the tag outlook-web-addins, not outlook-addin.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. Could you please let me know when 1.7 will be compatible with OWA?

Comment: Also, if there is an example manifest for Outlook 2016/2019 that uses 1.7 requirement set?

Comment: Victor, you may want to submit another question (about when 1.7 will be compatible), so the Outlook team will see it and respond.  I am not part of the Outlook team.  I don't think you want to specify the latest requirement set unless your app absolutely requires the new functionality.  Otherwise you can state a lower requirement set to be more generally available, and newer functions will still be available IF you are on a platform where they work.  You can test what is available before you use it.  You are simply stating the **minimum** requirement set.

Comment: Old OWA will only support 1.6. New OWA supports 1.7 and future API sets. OnSend functionality in new OWA is in progress and we will announce preview soon. Brian is right, if you you are not using any of the APIs in requirements set 1.7 for your add-in then you should be fine with using 1.6 for your add-in.